# Guardar varios checkbox en base sql server y ajax

Tags: php, ajax, sql-server

AQUI ESTA EL AJAX

```js
$("#guardar_estudiante").submit(function(event) {
  $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", true);

  var parametros = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/nuevo_registro.php",
    data: parametros,
    beforeSend: function(objeto) {
      $("#resultados_ajax_estudiante").html("Mensaje: Cargando...");
    },
    success: function(datos) {
      $("#resultados_ajax_estudiante").html(datos);
      $('#guardar_datos').attr("disabled", false);
      load(1);
    }
  });
  event.preventDefault();
})
```

```html
HTML
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" id="guardar_estudiante" name="guardar_estudiante">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <input type="checkbox" name="CATEGORIA[]" value="2"> Padre estudiantes actuales del colegio<br>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="checkbox" name="CATEGORIA[]" value="3"> Abuelo estudiantes actuales del colegio<br>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="checkbox" name="CATEGORIA[]" value="4"> Padre de exalumnos del colegio<br>
    </div>
  </div>
  </br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <input type="checkbox" name="CATEGORIA[]" value="5"> Miembro Comité Central padres familia<br>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="checkbox" name="CATEGORIA[]" value="6"> Presidente Comité Central padres familia<br>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="checkbox" name="CATEGORIA[]" value="7"> Ex Miembro Comité Central padres familia<br>
    </div>
  </div>
  </br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <input type="checkbox" name="CATEGORIA[]" value="8"> Miembro Consejo Directivo<br>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="checkbox" name="CATEGORIA[]" value="9"> Presidente Consejo Directivo<br>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="checkbox" name="CATEGORIA[]" value="10"> Miembro de la Comunidad Judía<br>
    </div>
  </div>
  </br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <input type="checkbox" name="CATEGORIA[]" value="11"> Presidente CJE<br>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="checkbox" name="CATEGORIA[]" value="12"> Ex utoridad-directivo del colegio<br>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="checkbox" name="CATEGORIA[]" value="13"> Fundador<br>
    </div>
  </div>
  </br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <input type="checkbox" name="CATEGORIA[]" value="14"> Rector<br>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="checkbox" name="CATEGORIA[]" value="15"> Gerente<br>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="checkbox" name="CATEGORIA[]" value="16"> Director de sección<br>
    </div>
  </div>
  </br>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <input type="checkbox" name="CATEGORIA[]" value="17"> Jefe de Departamento<br>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <input type="checkbox" name="CATEGORIA[]" value="18"> Fallecida<br>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
    </div>
  </div>
  </br>
  </br>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="guardar_datos">Guardar datos</button>
</form>
<?php
if($_POST['CATEGORIA'] != ""){
     if(is_array($_POST['CATEGORIA'])){
      while(list($key,$value) = each($_POST['CATEGORIA'])){
       $sql3 = "INSERT INTO CATEGORIA_ALUMNO (ID_CAT, CED_ALUMNO)
        VALUES ('$value', '$CED_ALUMNO')";
      }
     }
    };
?>
```

MI PREGUNTA ES PORQUE SOLO SE ALMACENA EL ULTIMO CHECKBOX SELECCIONADO
PORFAVOR NECESITO ESA AYUDA ESTOY TRABAJANDO CON SQL SERVER Y PHP 7

Comment: Agregá el código donde corrés la sentencia de SQL. Hasta ahí solo estás guardando en `$sql3` un string. Lo más probable es que estés ejecutando la sentencia fuera del ´while´, por eso solo guarda el último checkbox.

Comment: Gracias estimado funciono